# Spatial Join in QGIS 2.2

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to spatially join point layers of some 12,000 women interviewed in Egypt to Egypt's polygon layers (administrative districts boundaries) using QGIS 2.2 and need some advice. I am a QGIS self-learner.

I have read many QGIS manuals, but I cannot complete the spatial join successfully. I have added the vector layers of both Egypt's women's GPS points and Egypt's polygons (district boundaries). I used the UTF-8 encoding. Whenever I attempt to join attributes by location, the following message appears "Input layers have non-matching CRS". However, when I check the CRS of both layers, I found it the same (EPSG:4326 - WGS 84).

Comment: How have you checked the CRSs? Are you able to view both layers  properly overlayed?

Comment: I have checked the CRSs by right clicking each layer, choosing the Properties tab, then choosing the General tab. I cannot view both layers properly overlayed. However, I can see each layer properly when I separately open it.

Comment: Tho QGIS is trying to use EPSG:4326 in both layers, they are actually not the same. You should check with your data origin what is the real CRS of the files. For Spatial join work properly both layers must overlap.

Comment: which Spatial Join tool are you using in QGIS?

Comment: I click the Vector tab, then click the Data Management Tools tab, then select "Join attributes by location".

Comment: I know the CRS of one shapefile but the coordinate system of the second layer is unknown, and there is no *.prj file. How I can identify its CRS?

Comment: I could not save the women's locations to a new layer, using the CRS of the administrative districts boundaries, because I do not know the CRS of the boundaries. No *.prj file is there and I do not have access to the supplier in the meantime. I just know the CRS of the women's locations. Therefore, I tried to save the boundaries to the CRS of the interview locations then do the spatial join, but it did not work either. What is your advice?

Answer (score 3):

After being reasonably certain of the correctness of the CRSs (check also the  on-fly projection option) you could use the [spatial query plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_spatial_query.html)

Comment: I know the CRS of one shapefile but the coordinate system of the second layer is unknown, and there is no *.prj file. How I can identify its CRS?

Comment: You can define it with the following Qgis command: Vector--> Data Management Tools--> Define Current projection

Comment: I could not save the women's locations to a new layer, using the CRS of the administrative districts boundaries, because I do not know the CRS of the boundaries. No *.prj file is there and I do not have access to the supplier in the meantime. I just know the CRS of the women's locations. Therefore, I tried to save the boundaries to the CRS of the interview locations then do the spatial join, but it did not work either. What is your advice?

Comment: it's very hard to do a spatial join with a layer with unknown CRS. I would recommend you open a new post